# Add 2 variables inside another variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a search variable taking the value of 2 others variables for search results
[image: screenshot]

But I don't manage to get the expected result (title + author). In a sense where the author value is not taking into consideration.
How can I write the following correctly the get both correct values (title + author) in the search variable?
Thank you

```
let title = document.getElementById('titre-livre').value;
let author = document.getElementById('auteur').value;
let search = title + author;
```

Comment: There are multiple options. Objects, arrays, combining them as a string like you currently are. What is the end goal? What will you use these values for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember to separate these values with a space:

```js
let search = [title, author].join(' ');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer... Tried to vote but showing -1. I don't get it. I pressed the top arrow

Comment: @HermannOuré It's because you can't vote up yet. It's a privilege that you'll get once you reach 15 reputation points.

Comment: @HermannOuré did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it Did solve my issue thank you